# how index.d.ts files was created for a js

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using an angular application that includes several js files (that was creating in other project), and i saw that under node_modules/@types there is a 'index.d.ts' file for each js file. 
I'm wondering how 'index.d.ts' was created? is the compiler scans the js files?

Comment: AFAIK .d.ts are created manually, but I am not 100% sure, so I will leave it as a comment.

Comment: can you include the package.json you are refering to?

Comment: The folders in `@types` are from packages which isn't  build from typescript. So to get typings on such a library, a separate package with definition can be made (manually).  You will see those under `devDependencies` in your `package.json`. Each of those should have an index file. Is It int he root of the folder you find this index file?

Comment: its under node_modules/@types/jsFileName/index.d.ts

Comment: Some of those are created manually, but you can also generate them by setting `--declaration` to `true` in `tsconfig.json`